# Why is the mips palindrome function not working according to specifications?

Tags: string, recursion, assembly, mips, palindrome

I'm trying to finish writing a mips palindrome function that "reads the same forward as backwards" and my function is not working as needed. This is hurting my brain and any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

A recursive definition of a palindrome is as follows:
Let the string S be represented as S = S1 S2 … SN, where N is the length of the string.

```
S is a palindrome
    if N = 0 or N = 1 or
    if N   2 and S1 = SN and the substring (S2 .. SN-1) is a palindrome.
```

Function Palin($a0, $a1)
Precondition:

$a0 holds the address of the first byte in the string (or substring) being tested while $a1 holds the length of the string (or substring)

Postcondition:

1 (true) is returned in the register $v0 if the given string (or substring) is a palindrome; otherwise, 0 (false) is returned in $v0.

```
.data
    prompt1:  .asciiz "Enter length of string to be read: "
    prompt2:  .asciiz "Enter the string "
    ItIs:     .asciiz "\nThe string IS a palindrome!"
    IsNot:    .asciiz "\nThe string is NOT a palindrome!"
    string:   .asciiz ""

    .text
    .globl main
main:       

    la  $a0, prompt1
    li  $v0, 4
    syscall

    li  $v0, 5
    syscall
    move $a1, $v0

    la  $a0, prompt2
    li  $v0, 4
    syscall

    addi $a1, $a1, 1
    la  $a0, string
    li  $v0, 8
    syscall

    addi $a1, $a1, -1

    jal  Palin

    bne  $v0, $zero, label1
    la   $a0, IsNot
    j    label2
label1:
    la   $a0, ItIs
label2:
    li   $v0, 4
    syscall

    li $v0 10
    syscall          
    nop


Palin:

# HERE IS THE FUNCTION

li  $v0, 10
    syscall
    addu    $ra, $zero, $s7     #restore $ra since the function calles
                                #another function
    jr      $ra
    add $zero, $zero, $zero
    add $zero, $zero, $zero

EndPalin:
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: I'm sorry I should have clarified. The function is the issue. When I execute the code, the 1st and 2nd prompts print, but after entering a string the program exits without printing whether "It is, or Is not." @smac89

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this:

```
Palin:

# HERE IS THE FUNCTION

li  $v0, 10  # These
    syscall  # lines
```

The value 10 is the trap to exit the program and since you loaded that into register `$v0` and then did a `syscall`, the program exits. Remove those offending lines and you should be on your jolly way.

HTH

Comment: Hmm, after removing the offending lines it now produces errors that read "Bad address in text read: 0x00000000,
Exception occurred at PC=0x00000004,
Bad address in text read: 0x00000004,
Exception occurred at PC=0x00000008"
@smac89

Comment: @MercedezB If you got that from your simulator, then I can't help you there. All I can say is to make sure you are exiting correctly so that mips does not try to read an invalid instruction thus causing it to behave erratically